# Stationarity restriction of a TGARCH process?

Tags: time-series, self-study, stationarity, garch

What is the stationarity/convergence restriction for a threshold GARCH model, [TGARCH](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0165188994900396)?

I know that for a GARCH model: $\alpha+\beta<1$, but I'm guessing it's not that simple for a TGARCH model.

Can anyone help me with this? I've looked around with no luck.

Comment: according to the paper of El Babsiri and Thomas, 1991, the stationarity constraint is beta²+(alpha²+(alpha+gamma)²)/+2*beta*(2*alpha+gamma)/sqrt(2pi). It has to be less than < 1.

Comment: @Rafik, can you give a proper reference to the paper you cite and explain what the terms are in the expression (especially gamma which does not occur in the OP's question)?

Answer (score 0):

[LA MODELISATION DE LA
VOLATILITE DES BOURSES
ASIATIQUES by Sanvi Avouyi-Dovi and Eric Jondeau](https://publications.banque-france.fr/sites/default/files/medias/documents/document-de-travail_58_1999.pdf)

according to the paper of El Babsiri and Thomas, 1991 cited in the link above, the stationarity constraint is :

$$
\beta^2+(\alpha^2+(\alpha+\gamma)^2)/+2*\beta*(2*\alpha+\gamma)/sqrt(2pi) < 1.
$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).